# How can I add text in a input through a keydown event

Tags: javascript, events, keydown

I'm working in an Angular7 project, and I want to write test to simulate data typed from a user. For this, I want to trigger some events to fill the input to be tested.
Example : I want to type "12.50" on the input, so I probably should send 5 events : `"1"`, `"2"`, `"."`, `"5"`, `"0"`

I know I could update the element value, but I really want to check the behaviour of the keydown (some characters are not allowed, such as letters for example).
I checked a lot of examples and questions but none of them worked for me. Is there a possibility to do this kind of think in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically create a *keydown* event with [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) and dispatch it from your `<input>` element.

While this will trigger any *keydown* handlers set on your `<input>` element, it **will not** have the effect of updating the value of the `<input>` as a real *keydown* would have.

```js
const txt = document.querySelector('#txt');

txt.addEventListener('keydown', ev => console.log(`key=${ev.key}`));

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  txt.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: '1'}));
  txt.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: '2'}));
  txt.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: '.'}));
  txt.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: '5'}));
  txt.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key: '0'}));
});
```

```html
<input id="txt"/>
<button id="btn">Dispatch "12.50"</button>
```

Comment: I can see the console logs but nothing happened concerning the input. I'm trying this under Google Chrome

Comment: That is what I mentioned; you can simulate the event but not its effect. You could easily add a line in the click handler that programmatically update the input element e.g. `txt.value = "12.50"`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that what you said. So, there is no way for you to simulate the effect by an event ? How could I unit test the behaviour of keydown (and check that user actually can't type a letter in my input for example)

Comment: I’d argue that this kind of testing is more of an integration test and would use things like Selenium Webdriver or Puppeteer for that.